# Creating a custom property class for multiple re-use within a class

Tags: c#, properties

Suppose I have a C# class that has multiple properties that all look like this:

```
private bool _var1Dirty = true;
private Double? _var1;
public Double? Var1
{
    get
    {
        if (_var1Dirty)
        {
            _var1 = Method_Var1();
            _var1Dirty = false;
        }
        return _var1;
    }
}
```

And the only differences between each of these properties would be:

1. The type of return var (in this case `Double?`, but could just as easily be `int`, `string`, etc)
2. The method call - `Method_Var1()` (Each property would have a different one)

Is there any way I could write this as a custom class?

Something along the lines of:

```
public class Prop
{
    public delegate T Func();

    private bool _dirty = true;
    private T _val;
    public T Val
    {
        get
        {
            if (_dirty)
            {
                _val = Func;
                _dirty = false;
            }
            return _val;
        }
    }
}
```

And then I could pass into it the:

1. Return type `T`
2. Method `Func`

(PS - I **know** this won't compile / is dead wrong, but I wanted to give an idea of what I'm looking for)

Any help / guidance would be really appreciated.

Thanks!!!

Comment: So are you setting `_var1Dirty` somewhere else? `Lazy<T>` might be useful if the goal is simply to delay retrieval until requested.

Comment: @mikez, I'm not setting it anywhere else - I set it in my `get` to false at the same time that I set my local variable. That way, it only runs the processor-intensive method once at the first call and, from then onwards, simply returns the previously calculated value. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yea that makes sense. Sounds like [`System.Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you **SO MUCH**, @mikez... Never heard of them before and going to look into it right now, then!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close. You can do something along the lines of this:

```
public class Dirty<T>
{
    public Dirty(Func<T> valueFactory)
    {
        this.valueFactory = valueFactory;
        dirty = true;
    }

    private Func<T> valueFactory;
    private bool dirty;
    private T value;

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (dirty)
            {
                value = valueFactory();
                dirty = false;
            }

            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

And you consume it like this:

```
Dirty<double?> dirtyDouble = new Dirty<double?>(() => SomethingThatReturnsADouble());
double? value = dirtyDouble.Value;
```

I'm not sure what the dirty checking actually does, but if you need someone more complicated than a `bool` you can always turn it into some `Func<T>` the checks for dirtiness.

**Edit:**

Given @mikez comment and your answer, you can save yourself the creation of the `Dirty<T>` class by using the built in [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which also guarantess thread safety:

```
public class F
{
    private Lazy<double?> lazyDouble = new Lazy<double?>(() => 
                                           MethodThatReturnsNullableDouble(), true);
    public double? Value 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return lazyDouble.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yuval, thank you so much!!! - I'm going to look into @mikez's suggestion (and your edit) since I've never even heard of `Lazy`, but you gave me exactly what I asked for. thank you!!!